# Parse object from firebase with JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have tried to figure this out with similar questions already asked, but can't seem to get it. This is what I get back from firebase:

> '{"users":[null,{"-JFhOFSUwhk3Vt2-KmD1":         {"color":"White","model":"650i","year":"2014","make":"BMW"},
>   "-JGW6vwYtnfoIxeQlwCq": {"color":"Red","model":"AMG","year":"2014","make":"Mercedes"}},{"-JFhNnaAq1rr_SHzJcIr":{"color":"Red","model":"F150 FX4","year":"2014","make":"Ford"}},{"-JFhYXNpUG3wSMcfB3Uz":{"color":"Blue","model":"AMG","year":"2014","make":"Mercedes"}},null,null,null,{"-  JFly1lt6UWj-r2985ed":{"color":"red","model":"650i","year":"2014","make":"bmw"}}]}'

These cars are from 2 different users, I would like to put the information in a table. How would I use parse to do this? Here is what the call looks like:

```
$scope.read = function () {
    $http.get(BaseUrl + ".json").success(function (data) {
        $scope.AllCars = data
    });
}
```

Right now I can login with each user and show the cars they have entered on a table using Angular. Every time time they add one, it automatically adds another row. I would like for any user to see their cars as well as every other users. My goal is to retrieve this data and put into a separate table. The information will be constantly changing so I assume I would need to set the code up to expect changes.

Here is my firebase data:

```
 users
 1
 -JFhOFSUwhk3Vt2-KmD1
 color: "White"
 make: "BMW"
 model: "650i"
 year: "2014
 -JGW6vwYtnfoIxeQlwCq
 color: "Red"
 make: "Mercedes"
 model: "AMG"
 year: "2014"
 2
 -JFhNnaAq1rr_SHzJcIr
 color: "Red"
 make: "Ford"
 model:  "F150 FX4"
 year: "2014"
 3
 -JFhYXNpUG3wSMcfB3Uz
 color: "Blue"
 make: "Mercedes"
 model: "AMG"
 year: "2014"
 7
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want all the cars in a single object:

```
var all={};
data.users.filter(Boolean).forEach(function(user){
  Object.keys(user).map(function(k){  all[k]=this[k];  }, user);
});

console.log(all);
```

which shows something like

```
Object {-JFhOFSUwhk3Vt2-KmD1: Object, -JGW6vwYtnfoIxeQlwCq: Object, -JFhNnaAq1rr_SHzJcIr: Object, -JFhYXNpUG3wSMcfB3Uz: Object, - JFly1lt6UWj-r2985ed: Object…}
```